# sql query or django filter for string

Tags: sql, django, django-models

hello i need a query that search in database and return a row that has most similarity from starting character with a value.
imagine, given string is 'abcdefghijklmnop'
our database table has a column named x and for this column, rows are:
1- 'a'
2- 'abc'
3- 'absde'
4- 'abcdef'
5- 'abcdefg'
6- '1abcdefg'

and it should return the row number 5

Answer (score 2):

In postgres exists a function for similarity, first create the extension that contains it

```
create extension pg_trgm;
```

after that select using a percentage of similarity like this (e.g. 80% or your desired value)

```
select x from "table" where similarity('abcdefghijklmnop', x)>0.35;
```

or the most similar string would be

```
select * from "table" order by similarity('abcdefghijklmnop', x) desc limit 1;
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c901e/2 and docs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html

Comment: thank you but i need most similar, not by percent, most similar that exists

Comment: Query added to get the most similar.

Answer (score -1):

best one i found is this:

```
SELECT id, 
FROM table        
WHERE '3552' LIKE prefix || '%'        
ORDER  BY prefix DESC        
LIMIT  1
```

thank you all

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32932625)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).